# invisible followers ps3

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I had a bloodhound and I accidentally told him to go home, so I caught up with him and told him to follow me. but he isn't following me and he is no where to be found is there a way to get it to recognize that I have no followers without out loading a previous save?